# Images does not appear in Bootstrap 4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, c#-4.0, bootstrap-4

I can't see images which are uploaded in wwwroot.
Images have different sizes. I am working in asp.net core and Bootstrap 4.1. I think this problem happened in Bootstrap.

[image]

My code:

```
@model Product
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="~/img/@Model.ImageURl" />
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">@Model.Name</h5>
            <small>
                <i class="fas fa-lira-sign"></i>@Model.Price
            </small>
          
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-centet">
            <a asp-controller="shop" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.ProductID" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Details</a>
            <a asp-controller="shop" asp-action="addtocart" asp-route-id="@Model.ProductID" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add to cart</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

> can`t see images which get from wwrroot images

If you store image files under **`wwwroot/img`** folder in your project, like below.

[image]

To display image in your view page, please check if you assign correct value (like below) to `ImageURl` of product object.

```
new Product
{
    ProductID = 2,
    Name = "xxx",
    Price = 9.9m,
    ImageURl = "pic1.PNG" //image file name
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, to troubleshoot the issue, you can try to check the actual request(s) to image resource(s) in browser F12 developer tools network tab and compare it with your actual folder structure and the value of `ImageURl` you stored/assigned.

And you can check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-files-in-web-root) that is about serving static files in ASP.NET Core.

> *Consider creating the wwwroot/images folder and adding the wwwroot/images/MyImage.jpg file. The URI format to access a file in the images folder is `https://<hostname>/images/<image_file_name>`.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check in the browser for the value of `img src`. Also what is the value of `@Model.ImageURl`? Remember that you should only take the file name (and extension) and remove extra path from your `@Model.ImageURl`.